# angularjs filter not working on i18n text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to apply a filter over a field which have a i18N translation but somehow it is not working as aspected. Here is a detail:
Html:

```
  <div>
        <input class="form-control filter" type="text" data-ng-model="activityFilter">
    </div>
 <tr data-ng-repeat="feature in features | orderBy: orderColumns | filter: activityFilter">

            <td>{{feature.classifier| i18n }}</td> </tr>
```

i18N translation:

For Swedish file:

```
  "CULTURE":"Kultur",
```

For English:

```
 "CULTURE":"Culture"
```

Now translation works perfectly when i change a translation flags. But when translation is swedish and if i try to search like "culture" it filter a records However on page it is showing records "Kulture". Same as if i try to search "Kulture" it give me empty result. 
Here are some screen shots.
This is a actual records:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is when i search using culture on same translation:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This is what filter give me result on same page when i try to search with Kulter:
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Can someone explain me why this is happening and how to resolve this.

------------- update screen shot ------

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: try filter like this filter:{CULTURE:activityFilter}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter is running on the "feature" object.
See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for a more detailed description.
Basically the filter runs recursively on all properties of the object.

However the object itself only holds the translation **key** "CULTURE", so that is what is filtered against.

You can pass either in a comparator to the filter (see the docs linked above) and do the translation in the comparator.

Or you do not use the default filter named "filter", but write a custom filter, see for example https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

Answer (score 0):

According to given information, your mapping is:

```
"CULTURE":"Kultur"
```

But you searched the word: `Kulture` in the screenshot. Can it be the reason?